# Can not install the System.Net.Http Nuget package on a project that supports Multi-Target framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-targeting

We were developing a .net application in .Net Framework 4 version. Then we decided to convert the application to multi-platform(net 40, net 45, net46, net47)

We converted the application to multi-target platform and began to install nuget packages. We noticed that the **System.Net.Http** package was not installed correctly. 

In the Net Framework 4 version we were using version 2.0.20710 of the System.Net.Http dll and the application was working properly. When I bought and installed the System.Net.Http package from Nuget, I saw that the package was only installed under the Nuget packages in net40 version. No other versions have been installed under the Nuget package

How can we install **System.Net.Http** package Nuget packages in net45, net46 and net47 versions?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I think problem is not with .NET 4.5.x, but with higher frameworks. One solution is to use Automatic Binding Redirects to target highest versions of the assemblies. That worked for me. What was a show stopper for me is Fostura.Cody not being able to embed this resources in my compiled .exe